# Embedded video in beamer presentation - strange behavior

Tags: beamer, embedding

I have two `.mp4` videos that I have to embed in my beamer presentation which uses [this template](https://github.com/pmichaillat/latex-presentation). I use the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{Animation}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        height=0.45\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        addresource=videos/video_1.mp4,
        flashvars={
            source=videos/video_1.mp4
            &autoPlay=true
            &loop=false,
            &controlBarAutoHide=false
            &controlBarMode=floating
            &scaleMode=letterbox
            &playButton=fancy 
        },
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
```

It works perfectly for video_1: when the slide appears the video automatically starts and continues.
But when I use the exact same code for video_2, nothing appears, nothing happens.
Compiler: pdfLatex of Overleaf
My OS: MACOS Monterey
My PDF Reader:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acrobat specifically requires the video to be encoded "in H.264 with AAC audio", while files named `.mp4` can have different encoding method.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html

While Adobe recommended using their Media Encoder, you can also use FFMPEG
to do the job, say:

https://superuser.com/questions/1551072/ffmpeg-how-do-i-re-encode-a-video-to-h-264-video-and-aac-audio